# React route not matching query string

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-dom, query-string

I want react route to match for `localhost:8945/?type=admin` adddress.I tried with following code but it is always rendering `Home` component.

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = "/?type=admin">        **this is not working**
              <Admin />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path = "/">
              <Home/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Whenever I type `localhost:8945/?type=admin` in url bar it should render `Admin` component (Without requiring any server api).

Comment: look here : https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

Comment: @Nokwiw I saw, but i did not get how to do that, Please can you help me to write `path=`

Comment: can you add your code when you try to change the url :
`<Link to='...' />`

Comment: @Nokwiw, Here i am not using any `<Link to=/>` ,My intension is whenver I type `localhost:8945/ ` in url bar it should show `Home ` component ( it is showing fine) .But whenever I type `localhost:8945/?type=admin ` in url bar it should show `Admin` componet. But it is not showing .

Comment: Ok, in this cas use just : `<Route exact path = "/admin"> <Admin />
</Route>`

Comment: You don't need to use a query params.

Comment: @Nokwiw, I tried with that also, i end up with ` Cannot GET /admin` .I do not want to create bakend api for `/admin` . So for that i am using query string

Comment: `/admin`don't create a backend API, sure you have a problem somewhere else

Comment: @Nokwiw, No, not like that if i use `path="/admin"` then i should have api to handle it right. for example `app.get('/admin',function....)` otherwise i will get `Cannot GET /admin` error right. 
I am new to `react` and `node js` so...

Comment: @Nokwiw,Thank you for your help, I got solution (answered),I was updated question

Comment: hi, check the discussion, I left you a msg

Answer (score 0):

got solution !

```
class App extends React.Component{
 constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        type:''
    };
  }
componentDidMount() {
  this.setUrlParams();
}

setUrlParams(){
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    this.setState({type : urlParams.get('type')})
  }
 

 render(){
   return {
                <div>

               {  this.state.type=== 'admin'
                 ? <Admin/>
                 : <Home/>
               }
               </div>

     }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Hi, check this out [Query Params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

Comment: This link is broken.